# Comparing attribute value with a random number (JavaScript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with comparing an attribute value and a random number (created in a separated function).
In my html I have several divs within a surrounding div.
Each div within the surrounding element has an attribute, called 'value', the first one contains the value: 1, the second one: 2, ...
Like this:

```
      <div id="Stage_placeholder_rectangles">
        <div id="Stage_placeholder_rectangles_red" value=0 width=25 height=25/>
        <div id="Stage_placeholder_rectangles_pink" value=1 width=25 height=25/>
        <div id="Stage_placeholder_rectangles_orange" value=2 width=25 height=25/>
        ...
      </div>
```

Now I want to compare the attribute 'value' with a random number, which was made to show random random colors:
The function is lik this:

```
function randomNumber(){
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        return random;
}


function randomColors(){
    while(pastRandom == newRandom){
        newRandom = randomNumber();
    }
    pastRandom = newRandom;
    switch(newRandom){
        case 0:
            stageRef.getSymbol("placeholder_colors").stop("red");
            break;
        case 1:
            stageRef.getSymbol("placeholder_colors").stop("black");
            break;
        case 2:
            stageRef.getSymbol("placeholder_colors").stop("yellow");
            break;
        case 3:
            stageRef.getSymbol("placeholder_colors").stop("green");
            break;
        case 4:
            stageRef.getSymbol("placeholder_colors").stop("orange");
            break;
        case 5:
            stageRef.getSymbol("placeholder_colors").stop("pink");
            break;
        case 6:
            stageRef.getSymbol("placeholder_colors").stop("blue");
            break;
        case 7:
            stageRef.getSymbol("placeholder_colors").stop("gray");
            break;
        case 8:
            stageRef.getSymbol("placeholder_colors").stop("purple");
            break;
    }
    checkColor(newRandom);
}
```

In my function checkColor, I want to compare the random number with the value that is stored in the attribute value of 'placeholder_rectagles_orange', 'placeholder_rectagles_red', ...
This is my function:

```
function checkColor(rnd){
    if(gameStarted){
        $("#Stage_placeholder_rectangles").click(function(e){
            if($("#"+e.target.id).attr("value") == rnd){
                console.log("right");
            }
            else if($("#"+e.target.id).attr("value") != rnd){
            console.log("false");
            gameOver = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is, that when I the right element (the one with the same value in his attribute 'value' as the random number, I get in my console: 
"right" and multiple times "false", even when my attributes value and random number are the same.

Comment: I don't get what you are doing here. If the game is started, then it sets up a `click` handler on the surrounding `div`? But `checkColor()` only gets called from within `randomColors()`, which gets called... when? Can you describe the desired behaviour a little better?

Comment: It's a game, in which you have to click the rectangle who's color corresponds with the text that appears on the screen.
Each rectangle has a value attribute with the values: 0,1,2,...
The different texts with the name of a color, are made visible depending on a random number. This random number corresponds with the rectangles value. So the text Red, appears with the number 0 and the value of the red rectangle is also 0.
Now I want to compare in a function the value in the attribute en the random number. To check if they match. But when I do this, I get either false and true.

Comment: I think I get it, not sure. Quickly put up a jsfiddle?

Comment: It's difficult to put it up in a jsfiddle, because it's made in adobe edge animate. So the html and css is not created in code...
Maybe I can send you the whole project ?

Comment: So, it shows 9 colours. And then at the top it shows the name of a colour, and you need to click the cell whose colour corresponds with the name shown?

Comment: Yes, the names of the colour are displayed depending on a random number.
This is done in:
switch(newRandom){
case 1: (show name red)
case 2: (show name blue)
...
}
So I think that each colour name corresponds with a the value in the switch. This value has to match with the value in the attribute 'value' of my rectangles.
But when I compare them in my function, I get either true and false when the values are matching.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem is the usage of `rnd`, which is not defined earlier, but we don't have all of your code.

Here it is working:

```
<div>Please click the colour: <span id="name"></span></div>
<p/>
<div id="Stage_placeholder_rectangles">
    <div id="Stage_placeholder_rectangles_red" class="square red" value=0 width="25" height="25"></div>
    <div id="Stage_placeholder_rectangles_pink" class="square pink" value=1 width="25" height="25"></div>
    <div id="Stage_placeholder_rectangles_orange" class="square orange" value=2 width=25 height="25"></div>
 </div>
<p/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

And the JS:

```
var colors = ["red","pink","orange"],
gameStarted = true, newRandom, pastRandom;

function randomNumber(){
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    return random;
}


var giveOption = function() {
    while(pastRandom == newRandom){
        newRandom = randomNumber();
    }
    pastRandom = newRandom;
    $("#name").html(colors[newRandom]);
};
$("#Stage_placeholder_rectangles").click(function(e){
    var val = $(e.target).attr("value"), 
        resultDiv = $("#result");
    if(val == newRandom){
        resultDiv.html("right!");
        giveOption();
    } else {
        resultDiv.html("Wrong! Sorry. Game over");
       gameOver = true;
    }
});

giveOption();
```

There also is a lot of stuff that could be simplified using arrays and jquery, but I left it for now.

Fully functional jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/obqmwLet/1/